# std::list of std::pairs with pointers

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

I'm writing some simple connected component code and running into a weird weird segfault.

My code is as follows; with some definitions first.

```
Node* node;

typedef std::pair<int, Node*> Edge;

struct Node {
    ...
    std::list<Edge> neighbors;
    ...
}
```

The code that segfaults is below:

```
if (node->neighbors.empty())
{
    node->label = label_set.make();
}
else
{
    Node* first_neighbor = node->neighbors.front().second;
    node->label = first_neighbor->label;
    int i = 0;
    for (list<Edge>::iterator it = node->neighbors.begin(); it != node->neighbors.end(); it++)
    {   
        i ++;
        Node* n2 = (Node*)it->second;
        node->label = label_set.merge(node->label, n2->label);
    }
}
```

The really really weird bit is the following:

```
(lldb) p node->neighbors
(std::list<std::pair<int, _Node *>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, _Node *> > >) $4 = size=1 {
  [0] = {
    first = 78
    second = 0x00d85520
  }
}
(lldb) p *it
(std::pair<int, _Node *>) $8 = {
  first = 0
  second = 0xa0a45254
}
(lldb) p n2
(Node *) $5 = 0xa0a45254
```

Seeing this, I understand the segfault. `n2` is set to a completely weird value. It's not in the list; am I not iterating the list correctly? Is `n2` filled with random data because it is out of the list bounds? But then how did my iteration escape the bounds? I'm clueless.

**EDIT:**
I'm definitely outside the list bounds: at the time of the segfault `i == 3`.

**EDIT2**
Could it have something to do with the way I keep track of the nodes?

https://gist.github.com/noio/3082a0f351edb1821e90

Comment: `(Node*)it->second;` don't put a cast here. It could hide errors if the types change.

Comment: Originally I had no cast. I just though that I could provoke an error this way. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: Nothing strikes out to me as wrong..

Comment: you want to be looking at the code that put that *weird* value in there in the first place

Comment: @PaulEvans it shouldn't be there! `p node->neighbours` shows the entire `std::list` contents. The value that `n2` ends up with is definitely not in there.

Comment: @Noio - You're using pointers.  We have no idea if you have already corrupted something when that code you posted is executed.  Better you post a simple but full example.

Comment: You may try commenting out that label setting code and seeing what happens. Maybe it is corrupting the iterator.

Comment: @MichałGórny, PaulMcKenzie so it is possible—likely even—that I have somehow corrupted the iterator from somewhere else. But that could be from anywhere, right? :uh-oh:

Comment: @Noio - Comment out the last line in the loop (the call to `label_set`) and see if the problem goes away.  If you put the line back in, and the problem shows itself again, then maybe that line is the issue.  If the list is indeed 1 element, but the loop goes 3 times, then the logical conclusion is that the `label_set.merge` function is either mutating the list you're iterating over, or corrupting memory in some way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the problem does not go away. Actually; It hits an infinite loop because there is no segfault to stop it xD.

Comment: @Noio - That is a very simple loop that goes from the first item to the last item in the list.  All you're doing (when you comment out the last line) is just getting the `it->second`.  That does no harm at all.  How can this loop be infinite?

Comment: How indeed: https://gist.github.com/noio/091f7a5d7d5402d75204

Comment: What if a certain node has zero neighbours? make sure that you initialize neighbours to NULL and add checking for it.

Comment: @Noio - Then you probably are accessing an invalid `node->neighbors`.  Or even `node` could be bogus.  Just because you see "good looking" values in your debugger does not confirm that the object you're looking at is valid.  That's why I mentioned pointers in the first comment -- somewhere along the way, you had to create those `nodes`, and maybe even `destroy` one or more at some point (we don't know since you didn't post a complete program). In the course of doing that, you could have mismanaged pointers in some way.

Comment: @Ashalynd that is why I have `if(!node->neighbours.empty())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possibly what is happening:

If you did comment out the last line in the for loop that calls `label_set.merge`, you're left with a simple loop that supposedly goes from the beginning to the end of a `std::list`.

The increment is there (even though it would be better to have done `++it`, but that's another story), plus all you're doing in the loop is retrieving `it->second`.  However, your loop, as you claim, runs forever.

Since this is the case, one conclusion is that either `node` is invalid, or that `node->neighbors` is invalid.  You need to check your code to make sure you're not mismanaging memory or pointers.  You may also be better off using a smart pointer as opposed to a raw pointer (maybe even a

`std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<Node>>`

if the Node pointer is indeed shared between various objects).

As to the debugger, you can have values that look ok within an invalid object.  What is probably happening is that the debugger is showing you what the values are of the various members in an invalid object.  Since the object is invalid, those values can be anything, including reasonable looking values.

Edit:

The link you posted here: https://gist.github.com/noio/3082a0f351edb1821e90

shows you obtaining the address of the last item in the `vector<Node>`.  This is dangerous if the vector resizes to a larger capacity, as a vector's iterators will become invalidated.  Do not hold onto pointer values that point to data within the vector, unless you can guarantee that the vector will not be resized in the time you're using the pointer.

Comment: Yes, most likely `node->neighbours` is invalid. Even asking for `size()` **before** the iteration sends it into an infinite loop; perhaps in the internal call to `std::distance(begin(), end())`. I will investigate. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: It's totally weird. It seems my data is invalidated in some arbitrary place; even while the debugger is paused on a break point. That would suggest some other thread messing with my stuff but I'm not using any threads! https://gist.github.com/noio/8c14a560738af1ee270c

Comment: @noio Please post your `Node` class in full. You are using a `vector<Node>`, and `Node` better have correct copy semantics if it is going to be used in a vector. In addition, `Node* node = &(graph.back());` A vector can invalidate iterators if the size is increased. So holding onto a pointer to one of the vector's items is going to be dangerous.

Comment: AH! THAT MUST BE IT ""A vector can invalidate iterators if the size is increased"" This was unknown to me, the size of the vector definitely increases constantly! I am also holding on to the pointers while that is happening. 

So I guess I should turn `graph` into a `vector<Node*>` too; and allocate the `Node`s dynamically.

Comment: @noio - Probably that is the reason, that the vector is being resized.  However, why all the dynamic allocation?  If indeed your Node needs to be shared, then use a `std::shared_ptr<Node>` and not a `Node*`.  By constantly having to manage dynamically allocated memory, more dynamic allocation will just have you jumping from the frying pan into the fire.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Now that I'm refactoring, might as well use `shared_ptr` for the `graph` (the owner of the nodes) and `weak_ptr` for the `node_matrix`.

Comment: @noio - I updated my answer to include your latest edit to the question.  If the answer addresses the issue, you can accept the answer (I guess you already upvoted).

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that the call to `label_set.merge` removes the current node from the
`node->neighbors` list, invalidating the `it` iterator.  When it returns you attempt to increment the iterator to continue the loop, but since it has been invalidated (probably now points at freed memory) it goes off into never-never land.

Since you don't show what `label_set` is or how `merge` works, its impossible to tell.

Another possibility is that you've corrupted the heap somehow, and have dangling pointers pointing around in ways that cuase things to be overwritten randomly.  Try running with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and see if that can tell you more about what is going wrong.